# Blogging engine with built in SASS/Compass and HAML

Tags: blogs, haml, markdown, sass, compass-sass

I absolutely love what HAML and SASS have done for my design habits. I want to switch my blog over from Wordpress to something that supports SASS, Compass, and HAML natively (bonus points for Markdown and Liquid support). What's out there?

Typo and Mephisto don't seem to mention it, and I don't think I want a static blog, as nice as Jekyll seems (plus you have to jump through hoops for SASS and HAML in Jekyll, which I'm not sure I like).

I know that it's not extremely hard to have the directories watched and automatically compiled, but that's an extra layer of complexity I'd avoid if I could.

Is there anything out there for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Nesta CMS](http://nestacms.com/). It's based on Sinatra, is pretty light, supports all of the [templating options that Sinatra supports](http://nestacms.com/docs/design/templating-engines), has a nice plugin system and can be [hosted for free on Heroku](http://nestacms.com/docs/deployment/heroku).

For an appropriate example site driven by Nesta, have a look at [The Sass Way](http://thesassway.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Careful! You don't want to use Haml unmodified in a CMS. The reason is that Haml can embed any Ruby code, and that therefore your CMS pages will be able to do nasty things like

```
%h1 My Cat
%p This is a picture of my cat.
- User.delete_all
```

I understand, though, that [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org) can use Haml; I suppose they must have sandboxed it to use Radius (their limited template language) instead of full Ruby -- at least I hope they did!

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://middlemanapp.com which is pretty awesome.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't really answer your question, but have you thought about using something like [ActiveAdmin](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin) or [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to build a simple one of your own? You could still install compass or [bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon) or whatever you like.

UPDATE:

Just found this, it's called [Octopress](http://octopress.org) - it runs on jekyll but it has built-in support for Sass and Compass, and there is plugin/converter for haml. It looks like a good tool.

Comment: That's a pretty good alternative I guess, since nobody else seems to have any recommendations... I guess I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to Octopress which might be worth looking at too